# How to view the full Postgres Query error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Whenever I have a Postgres Error, it dumps something like this

```
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::CreateNewMatchesJob::MultiTenantNamespacing>)> User.all.each { |user| BreakerScoresJob.new.perform(user.id) }
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "identities"
LINE 1: ...ies".* FROM "excelon_auth_identities" WHERE "identitie...
                                                        ^
: SELECT "excelon_auth_identities".* FROM "excelon_auth_identities" WHERE "identities"."external_identity_type" = $1 AND "excelon_auth_identities"."id" IN (2)
from /Users/jeeves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@gb/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:641:in `prepare'
```

This is an incredibly difficult format becuase the query is always cut off, and I'd like to see the full query it's executing so I can get some better context on which line it's stumbling on.

Is there any way to view the whole query?

Thanks!

Comment: In the log exists the complete query `SELECT "excelon_auth_identities".* FROM "excelon_auth_identities" WHERE "identities"."external_identity_type" = $1 AND "excelon_auth_identities"."id" IN (2)` and the error is related to the `from` and the `where` in where it expects for `identities` but in the from only exists `excelon_auth_identities`

Answer (score 0):

Use `#to_sql` on whatever AR or AR collection object you're having a problem with.

For instance, in your example you might use `User.all.to_sql`. You probably need to add `puts` in front it because the string will be escaped.

I suspect, though, that you'll need to dig into BreakerScoresJob's initialize method and do the `to_sql` call there. (Sorry, not enough code here to help with that.)